# position modal's loader animation correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use [ConnorAtherton loaders](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/loaders.css) on my page.  Specifically the pac man one but having some issues getting it to look right.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="js/libs/jqueryui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="js/libs/jquery.tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/jquery.tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="bower_components/loaders.css/loaders.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="bower_components/loaders.css/loaders.css.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="js/libs/jquery.tablesorter/css/theme.blackice.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <input type="file" id="logSelector" name="log" title="Select a log file" onchange="logSelected();"/>
            <input type=button id="remoteLogSelector" value="remoteLog" style="display: none" title="Select a remote log file" onclick="sftpLogin();"/>
        </header>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <p>Processing File.</p>
                <div class="loader-inner pacman">
                    <div class="pacmanDot"></div>
                    <div class="pacmanDot"></div>
                    <div class="pacmanDot"></div>
                    <div class="pacmanDot"></div>
                    <div class="pacmanDot"></div>
                </div>
                <input type = "button" name="cancel" value = "cancel" onclick = "cancelRead()" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.pacman {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
}
```

[image]
Some how it is outside of its containing div (to far to the left)

So I add some padding

```
.pacman {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

But then the child divs, which control the dots, do not align to the pacman
[image]
Its hard to see but now the white dots are to far to the left (you can see the tip of one outside of the white box), though the pacman is aligned how I want.

I have tried adding another class pacmanDot for the empty divs and adding padding in the css for them.  but that did not effect the position at all

How can I move both the pacman and the dots to the right?

Comment: Do you have this in your '<head>' code?  '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../loaders.css"/>'  Here is the sample html code the have https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/loaders.css/blob/master/demo/demo.html  Post your entire html code

Comment: its all posted but yes the link is there, dont think it would work at all without that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was super simple, should have thought of it sooner!
I encapsulated the pac man div inside another than padded that

HTML

```
    <div id="loadingModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>Working.....</p>
            <div class="loadersPacman">
                <div class="loader-inner pacman">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*div containing the pacman animation, had to do this to make it look right*/
.loadersPacman{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```